# Is it possible to change my display name on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: support, display-names

Currently it uses my full name and rather it didn't. I login via a Google account if that has any affect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your profile page. Go to the "Edit Profile & Settings" tab. Change the "Display Name:" field. Save to all of your communities.